# Packaging an apk with js bundle included in dev mode in React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native, apk

Is it possible to create a signed apk with js bundle included (not requiring development server) in **dev mode**, not release mode in React Native Android?

Answer (score 2):

In your project's `android/app/build.gradle` insert

```
project.ext.react = [
  // supply additional arguments to the packager
  extraPackagerArgs: ["--dev", "true"]
]
```

before `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"`

This will force packager to run in dev mode when you execute `assembleRelease` task

There are more options in `build.gradle`, you can read comments inside the file.